# Upload an image on slack returns invalid payload

Tags: python, slack

I tried to upload an image on a slack channel, but it returns me `invalid_payload` as response, any idea why?

This is below my post request:

```
import json 
import sys
import requests

file_path = '/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/file.jpg'

with open (file_path, 'rb') as f:

    payload = {"filename": "file.jpg",
            "token": XXX,
            "channels": "test_pandl"}

    requests.post("https://slack.com/api/files.upload", params=payload, files={'file': f})

    print(response.content)
    print(f)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of

`file_path = '/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/file.jpg'`

maybe you should try using full path including your disk drive name?

Ex: `file_path = 'C:/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/file.jpg'`

Comment: no because i can open the file, the error is related to my post request

Comment: But even if you can, why are you passing `file.jpg` instead of the full path for the file?